# Unable to save background subtracted video Python openCV

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have a input text file which contains the names of the images which I have to put together into a video and then apply background subtraction on the video and then save the output.

I tried this:

```
# convert images to video
f = open('files_harsha.txt','r+')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('harsha_output.avi',fourcc, 10.0, (1344,1024))
for line in f:
    frame=cv2.imread(line.strip())
    out.write(frame)
#    cv2.imshow('1',frame)
#    cv2.waitKey(0)

out.release()
```

The above snippet works correctly, saving the video. Then I perform the background subtraction and try to save the output, as shown below:

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture('harsha_output.avi')
size = (int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
video = cv2.VideoWriter('harsha_subtractor.avi', fourcc, 10.0,size)
fgbg= cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(varThreshold=50,history=4)

while (1):
    ret, img = capture.read()
    if ret==True:
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(img)
        video.write(fgmask)
        #cv2.imshow('forehead',fgmask)

    else:
        capture.release()
        video.release()
        break

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am able to see the background subtracted video but I am unable to save the file. Why am I having this issue?

I am using Python 2.7 within the Anaconda IDE (Spyder) and am using openCV 3.x

Comment: Are you getting an error? A blank video file?

Comment: @EliezerBernart I'm getting a blank video

Comment: Great! Did you try to normalize the image before writing to the file? You can use `cv2.convertScaleAbs` for that.

Maybe could be something else. What is the file size of your output video?

Comment: I suspect the problem is due to the [`fgmask` being a 1-channel image](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d7b/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.html#a3fb6b359c0c6753d20462dff0a48239f) (grayscale), whereas your [VideoWriter](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ac3478f6257454209fa99249cc03a5c59) is configured to expect colour images.

Comment: @EliezerBernart I tried normalizing the images with `img = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img)` but I am still getting a blank video.

Comment: @HarshavardhanRamanna OK, and what about if you do the opposite, convert the `fgmask` to RGB? Oh, and one more thing to eliminate, although that's probably OK -- does `size` contain a meaningful value?

Comment: @DanMašek It worked! I had to combine both the normalizing as well as ensuring that the VideoWriter was expecting greyscale values. Could you write the comment as an answer? I will mark it as the correct one

Comment: @HarshavardhanRamanna Glad it helped. Feel free to self-answer, I just provided some ideas while you've done done work and have a working solution on hand. (You may translate as "I'm feeling lazy right now." ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record. As suggested by [dan-mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek), the `fgmask` is a 1-channel image, thus the `VideoWriter` fails showing the following `error: (-215) scn==2 & (scn == 3 || scn == 4)`.
I solved passing the `isColor=False` argument to `VideoWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem. Add `isColor=False` argument to the `VideoWriter`.

Change certain portion of your code accordingly as shown:

```
video = cv2.VideoWriter('harsha_subtractor.avi', fourcc, 10.0, size, 
isColor=False)
```